# Redirect customer to login if not logged in when proceeding to checkout

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to redirect customers, who are not logged in, when they push the "proceed to checkout button" on my cart page but nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```
function custom_redirect_checkout(){
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ){

  wp_redirect( 'https://www.domain.co/login/', 301 );

  exit;
  }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'custom_redirect_checkout' );
```

Comment: Please post the error here.

Comment: There is no error, it's just that nothing happens when I click the "proceed to checkout" button.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' is an action, not a filter.

See http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout/.

For the difference between actions and filters check out this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks